# Python event scheduling

Tags: python, tkinter, scheduling

I'm working on a Python (Tkinter) app for an irrigation timer.  The user enters the days of the week for each valve using the following screen:
[image]

I'm able to process the data from the checkboxes to get the days of the week:

```
['Sunday', 'Tuesday', 'Friday', 'Monday', 'Thursday', 'Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Friday', 'Wednesday', 'Saturday'].
```

But, I need to know how many days are in between each "on" day.  For example, for Valve 1, 2 days between Sunday and Tuesday and three days from Tuesday to Friday, but I don't know how to get the number days from the Friday to the next Sunday.  Can anyone suggest an approach?  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: One possibility: concatenate two copies of the weekly list.  The distance from Friday to Sunday (the one from the second copy) would be determined in exactly the same way that you determine distances that lie within a single week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def daysDifference(day1:int, day2:int):
    """
    day1: The index of the first day.
    day2: The index of the second day.
    Returns the time from one to the next.
    """
    if day1 <= day2:
        return day2 - day1
    else:
        return 7 - day1 + day2
```

I'm pretty sure this will work.