# Irrigation scheduling

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to code an irrigation controller.  I have a preliminary tkinter UI that uses checkbuttons to get the days of the week when 4 valves will be turned on:
[image]

After I've checked the boxes, the data looks like this:

```
raw_data= [
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
]
```

Where '1's represent days that the valve will be turned on.  What I need to know (and don't know how to write the code for) is a way to calculate the number of days since the last irrigation.  It's easy for the second day of the week, I just subtract the weekday index for the second day from the first.  For Valve 1 in the present example that would be Thursday and Monday (3 days).  But...on the first day of the week, I need to know how many days since the valve was turned on the previous week.  Again, for Valve 1, on Monday I need to know how many days since the previous Thursday (4 days).  It's a trivial calculation for me, but I can't seem to get how to code it so a computer would understand.

What approach can I take (what logic can I use) to solve this problem?

Comment: Python has a lot of functions for dealing with dates. For example, you might want to read up on [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) which can compute how many days between two dates.

Comment: Is it the same question as your last question? It is already answered.

Comment: " It's a trivial calculation for me, but I can't seem to get how to code it so a computer would understand." Then start by writing down, in complete English sentences, on a real piece of paper with a real pen or pencil, the exact steps that you take when you perform that "trivial calculation". Second: Unless the question is **specifically** about how to manipulate Tkinter widgets in order to display the result, the question is **not about Tkinter at all**; it is about how to do the calculation. We don't care about the context of your program except where needed to **understand the question**.

Comment: @acw1668 indeed, I can't see how this isn't a duplicate of the previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74870326. But I already voted to close for a different reason, so I can't dupe-hammer it now.

Comment: Since I've had to change my approach I didn't think the previous answer would apply.  I'll take another look.

Comment: The answer in your last question has told you how to calculate the days between two weekdays, so I don't understand what the problem is on this question.  Also it is better to state what you want on the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it in the following way.

Let's take as an example the valve 1 whose array would be: `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`.

As you say, the easiest thing to do is to subtract the indexes, so we simply add the same array at the end to repeat the week with the same data.

```
a = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
b = a+a

aux = []

for i,v in enumerate(b):
    if v == 1:
        aux.append(i)

print(aux)
```

This code adds in `aux` index each time it finds a 1 in the array. Now we only need to subtract. In this case the last value does not interest us, so if you want you can remove it with `aux.pop()`.

Output:

```
[0, 3, 7, 10]
```

Where 3-0=3 and 7-3=4

Comment: This is an elegant solution to my problem...thanks!  It also allows for selecting more than 2 days of the week to turn on the valves.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I now have two solutions to the problem I raised.  The one above and one that I came up with myself based on a answer to my previous question.  Unless I'm mistaken (which is possible, since I'm a beginner Python coder), the answer to the previous question didn't include today's date as a benchmark.  Once I put that into the code:

```
if today > day1:
    days_since_last_irrigation = day2 - day1
else:
    days_since_last_irrigation = ((day1 - day2) + 7)
```

I started to get results that made sense.  This exercise is an illustration that there's more than one way to solve most problems.

Answer (score 0):

Easier way from @FG94.

```
a = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
b = a + a

aux = [i for i,v in enumerate(b) if v]
print(aux)
```